# Exceptions thrown by Settings.Default.Save()?

Tags: c#

Bizarre - I cannot locate a list of common/likely exceptions for `Settings.Default.Save()` in the MSDN library.

`UnauthorizedAccessException` is a good one to catch because it facilitates feedback that the user can use to correct the problem about why the user's settings could not be saved.  In addition it is part of the System library.

Does it also make sense to catch and handle IO exceptions such as `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`?  The user may have some serious system issues if the system created user directory for the app's settings does not exist.

Are there others you catch and handle for `Settings.Default.Save()`?  Running code search through Google I am surprised that very few people catch and handle `UnauthorizedAccessException` - maybe its likelyhood is so low it is not worth the effort.

Thoughts?

Thanks!